# jQuery and IE, object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've used this bit of code to get a drop-down style menu on a website.
It works absolutely fine on all browsers other than IE, and even works fine on IE except on this one page where I get the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Here is where IE tells me the error is, this part is in a "header" file that is loaded first before the rest of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-one li").hover(
        function(){ $("ul", this).fadeIn("fast"); }, 
        function() { } 
    );

if(document.all){
    $("#nav-one li").hoverClass("sfHover");//THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    };
});

$.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
    return this.each(function(){
    $(this).hover( 
        function() { $(this).addClass(c);  },
        function() { $(this).removeClass(c); }
        );
    });
};    
</script>
```

I don't think the error is in the code because it works fine with no errors on every single page except for this one, this is also the only page that uses additional jQuery code.
The rest of the jQuery code runs fine on the page, only the drop-down doesn't work when hovering over the menu items.
If anyone can help me find the answer it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What's `hoverClass`? It's not part of jQuery itself. Do you need to include a certain plugin perhaps?

Comment: Its defined under the if statement.

Comment: it is created in the script itself `$.fn.hoverClass = `

Comment: @Willian Van Rensselaer, that was correct u clever bastard! Stupid IE, hate it so much! please submit as a response and i will accept as correct!

Comment: You don't need a `.each` in `hoverClass`, you can just `return this.hover(function(){}...`.

Comment: @Adam not sure thats the "correct" way to thank someone :-(

Comment: I don't think there's enough data here to troubleshoot this sort of intermittent issue; particularly if it only happens on one page; that suggests that it's going to turn out to be an obscure detail about that page (like the doctype)

Comment: And I stand corrected, I guess, by the prescient William?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `hoverClass`, it has not yet been defined. You need to declare `$.fn.hoverClass` at the top of your code.

```
$.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
    return this.each(function(){
    $(this).hover( 
        function() { $(this).addClass(c);  },
        function() { $(this).removeClass(c); }
        );
    });
};   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-one li").hover(
        function(){ $("ul", this).fadeIn("fast"); }, 
        function() { } 
    );

if(document.all){
    $("#nav-one li").hoverClass("sfHover");//THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing `$.fn.hoverClass` before it's being declared.  You should declare/load all plugins before any other code, just to be safe.

Also, in `$.fn.hoverClass`, you don't need `.each`, you can just `return this.hover()`. (Also, you don't need a semicolon after `if` statements).

```
$.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
    return this.hover( 
        function() { $(this).addClass(c);  },
        function() { $(this).removeClass(c); }
    );
}; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-one li").hover(
        function(){ $("ul", this).fadeIn("fast"); }, 
        function() { } 
    );

    if(document.all){
        $("#nav-one li").hoverClass("sfHover");//THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 because your indenting was more accurate and so less confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin is getting overridden by jQuery. May be you have included jQuery multiple times on this page. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
    return this.each(function(){
    $(this).hover( 
        function() { $(this).addClass(c);  },
        function() { $(this).removeClass(c); }
        );
    });
};  

    $("#nav-one li").hover(
        function(){ $("ul", this).fadeIn("fast"); }, 
        function() { } 
    );

if(document.all){
    $("#nav-one li").hoverClass("sfHover");//THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    };
});
```

Comment: it's simply because `$.fn.hoverClass` doesn't exist at the point it is called in OP...

Comment: @Esailija - Why it doesn't exist? If the OP is adding it(check the code again).

Comment: remove the `if ( document.all )` from code and try to run the code in any browser, it will fail because `$.fn.hoverClass` is not assigned yet. As is, it will work in other browsers because they don't have document.all and the if block won't get executed. `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hoverClass'` In google chrome

Comment: The plugin is added outside $(document).ready(). As long as it is added outside it does not matter before or after.

Comment: Also OP has mentioned the same code runs in other browsers in IE. Only on this page it is giving that error. So it makes sense you revisit your comments

Comment: `jQuery` makes sure the `DOM` is ready before executing `ready` handlers.

Comment: It runs in other browsers because the if block doesn't get executed in other browsers: `if( document ) {"this if block got executed";}
//"this if block got executed"
if( document.all ) {"this if block got executed";}
//undefined`. Document ready can fire synchronously means that the passed function is instantly fired before moving on to the assigment.

Comment: Check OP's question again, it works in IE also in other pages. " It works absolutely fine on all browsers other than IE, and even works fine on IE except on this one page where I get the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error."

Comment: that is the side effect of `can fire synchronously`: if it fires asynchronously, it will work, if it fires synchronously it won't work. You can make sure it works in both cases just by doing the assignment before document ready call or before the call to `$.fn.hoverClass`

Comment: You need to go through `jQuery` basics to make your fundamentals clear. If makes sure that `DOM` is ready before calling all the `ready` handlers.

Comment: No, if the document is ready when you do document.ready, the passed callback is fired synchronously in older jQuery. `// If the DOM is already ready
  if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
   // Execute the function immediately
   fn.call( document, jQuery );`